# Does Google Cloud Functions reconnect to my MongoDB Client for each HTTP request?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to migrate my Node/Express REST API to Google Cloud Functions, and was noticing some performance issues. I am receiving 404 errors on all my API routes while waiting for my Functions to "spin up" after a period of inactivity. I was curious if this was related to my implementation. Here is my Express serverless "server", written in Typescript (`index.ts`):

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as express from 'express'
import { MyApi } from './server'

const app: express.Application = MyApi.bootstrap().app

export const myApp = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Next, here is `server.ts`

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb'

require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' })

export class MyApi {
  app: express.Application = express()
  mongoDbUri: string = process.env.MONGO_URI

  static bootstrap(): MyApi {
    return new MyApi()
  }

  constructor() {
    this.connectToDb(this.mongoDbUri)
  }

  connectToDb(uri: string) {
    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, db) => {
      if (err) {
        this.handleNoDbError(err)
      }
      setApiRoutes(app: express.Application, db)
    })
  }
}
```

I've stripped a lot of the redundant code for the sake of simplicity, but hopefully this is enough for you to get the idea. I am asking Functions to expose some API endpoints. First, I am using connection pooling to make a single Mongo connection, then I pass that connection (`db`) down to my routes. These route endpoints in turn make a `find()` request to my MongoDB Atlas database, and pass those results on to my app.

I deployed a version of this code and it is functioning ok, in that it fetches results properly. However I am concerned about the slow performance and intermittent 404 errors (compared to a dedicated Node/Express server on Heroku, for example).

I was wondering if my problems are related to the Mongo Client. Is it connecting to my database every time a request is made to Functions? Once my Functions wake up after inactivity, do they persist the same Mongo DB connection across all future requests? I'm new to serverless so I guess I'm confused about whether my Functions start up and stay up during execution, then "shut down" after going idle.

Can supply live links if needed.

Comment: I answered briefly how the system works below. I'd recommend against worrying about things you can't control. If you encounter time-out related problems in practice, I'd appreciate steps on how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time your function is executed in a new instance, it will have to connect to the Mongo server.

This means that the reconnect will at least happen:

- After a period of inactivity, if Cloud Functions has spun down your instances.
- When there is an increase in activity, as Cloud Functions spins up additional instances.

It may also happen intermediately if your client library does connection management. But since that doesn't depend on the Cloud Functions environment, I can't comment on it.

Comment: Here is an early beta deployment of my PWA: https://ghost.kriyate.co. On initial page load, all my routes give 404s, but after a minute or so of reloading, it settles down and works as intended. I think I can improve the user experience by piping an RxJS `.retry()` operator on the front-end (Angular's HttpClient), in order to give the Cloud Function some time to spin up.

Comment: I just found this too, look forward to playing with it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries. I had another question, you have an "Optimizing Networking" (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking) list of tips and tricks for persisting http and axios connections, etc. Are there any equivalent tricks for MongoDB?